# Create a class with fields automatic in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

See my code:

```
interface IMyInterface{
  a:string
  b:string
  c:number
  //and more...
}
class MyClass extends IMyInterface{ //err 1
  //the class has all fields from IMyInterface
  constructor(opt:IMyInterface){
    for(let key in opt){
      this[key]=opt[key] //err2
    }
  }
  myOtherMethods(){}
}
```

I want a class has all fields extends from an interface(returned from a HTTP request) and auto construct it with values. Above code has 2 errors:

1. Classes can not extends an interface, but if I use `implements`, I need to write all fields and types in the class again.
2. The type of the `key` is string, and I can not access the field trough it on `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rewrite `IMyInterface` to be class and then extend eg

```
class BaseClass {
  public a: string = 'foo';
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(this.a); // 'foo'
  }

  public someMethod() {
    console.log(this.a); // 'foo'
  }
}
```

Interfaces are type information only. They don't have any semantic meaning (like default value)

Comment: That's right , but I think there are some shortages in semantic. Interfaces are just the shapes of data, as a protocol in data transfer, not an instance. And more there maybe extra objects generated while ts compiling.

Answer (score 0):

what about generic type

```
interface IMyInterface {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: number;
  // and more...
}

class MyClass<T extends IMyInterface> { // or whatever interface you want
  public data: T;

  constructor(opt: T) {
    this.data = opt;
  }
}
```

if you need them to  be exactly class fields you can check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54207173/classes-keyof-in-typescript)